# Combine two jQuery-json functions. Right way

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm totally newbie in jQuery and i wonder if it is possible to combine these two functions.

As you can see, the first function is used to load json data to trigger a click.

The second function is used to toggle view for the list items.

Could you help me, and show me the good way to combine these functions!?

When the json file is loaded, it will be create the list elements (li), and the toggle will be able to toggle these list elements (li).

IMPORTANT: actually, my code don't work (the toggle function not work fine).

Here is the code of 1st functions :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ----------------------
    // JSON INFOS
    // ----------------------

    $(".color-list.one li:first-child").on('click', function() {
        $.getJSON("result.json", function(data) {
        //Handle my response

        $('ul.elements-list').html(
            '<li class="elements-item"><span class="tog">' + data.name + '</span><div class="togcont hidden">' + data.info + data.size + '</div></li>');

            //alert(data);
        });
    });


});
```

The code of 2nd function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // ----------------------
    // TOGGLE BULLZ
    // ----------------------
    $(".tog").click(function(){
        var obj = $(this).next();
            if($(obj).hasClass("hidden")){
                $(obj).removeClass("hidden").slideDown();
                $(this).addClass("bounce");
            } else {
                $(obj).addClass("hidden").slideUp();
                $(this).removeClass("bounce");
        }
    });



});
```

Comment: These two blocks of code have nothing to do with one another (that I can tell).  You have to describe what you're trying to accomplish before we'd have any idea how to help.

Comment: When the json file is loaded, it will be create the list elements (li), and the toggle will be able to toggle these list elements (li).

Comment: @jfriend00 - the second block tries to assign a click handler to elements created dynamically by the first, so that's something we can (and I did) help with. Although Gilbert: even after your edit the question still doesn't actually say that your current code doesn't work. It would be clearer to spell out explicitly what the desired behaviour is and what the current behaviour is rather than leaving it to us to guess what is broken. Your description of the first function being "used to load json data to trigger a click" is backwards: a click triggers a load of data, not the other way around.

Comment: @nnnnnn - that's fine.  The OP's question could have explained that connection as I didn't see it.  I see sooooo many poorly written questions here that I get tired of trying to figure out the puzzle when a little clear communication would draw a lot more people to participate and get more answers that actually address what they're asking about.

Comment: Sure @nnnnnn, i will be edit my question now! But be indulgent, im newbies and i'm french with double dutch language! ;-)

Comment: Sorry for this @jfriend00, for future i will make more effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$(".tog").click()` it only binds to whatever elements match the `".tog"` selector *at that moment* so won't work on elements that you add dynamically later. You can instead use the delegated syntax of `.on()` like this:

```
$('ul.elements-list').on("click", ".tog", function(){ ...
```

...which will bind the click handler to your list, but only execute your function if the click occurred on an element in that list that matches the `".tog"` selector in the second parameter *at the time of the click.* And within the handler `this` will be set to the `".tog"` element that was clicked.

Also you can put all your code in a single document ready handler assuming all the code is in the same file.

Also your `obj` variable is a jQuery object, so you can call jQuery methods on it directly like `obj.hasClass()` rather than wrapping it in `$()` again as `$(obj).hasClass()`.

So try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".color-list.one li:first-child").on('click', function() {
        $.getJSON("result.json", function(data) {
            //Handle my response
            $('ul.elements-list').html(
               '<li class="elements-item"><span class="tog">' + data.name + '</span><div class="togcont hidden">' + data.info + data.size + '</div></li>');
        });
    });

    $('ul.elements-list').on("click", ".tog", function(){
        var obj = $(this).next();
        if(obj.hasClass("hidden")){
            obj.removeClass("hidden").slideDown();
            $(this).addClass("bounce");
        } else {
            obj.addClass("hidden").slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass("bounce");
        }
    });

});
```